# Colon before quotations

Tags: ruby, symbols, literals

I tried this:

```
:"asdfas"
# => :asdfas
```

1. The console output seems to indicate that I have declared `:asdfas`. Do I understand it correctly? If not, what does the output actually mean?
2. In reality, is it common to use colon before string? If yes, what is it used for?

EDIT:

Daniel Contreras mentions that "every output is the return value of that function or object", so the follow-up question is: Why isn't `:"asdfas"`?

```
:"asdfas"
# => :asdfas  # why not :"asdfas"
```

Why are the quotation marks around `asdfas` stripped down in the output?

Comment: "use colon before string"-- It is not a colon before a string. colon preceding a pair of quotes is a single symbol literal expression.

Comment: I don't quite understand what "a single symbol literal expression" means.

Comment: In this context, is `:"asdfas"` equivalent to `:asdfas`?

Answer (score 1):

From my limited knowledge in ruby, every output is the return value of that function or object. e.g.

```
> foo = 1+2
=> 3

> "#{foo} bar"
=> "3 bar"
```

And to answer number 2: Yes, it is quite commonly used as an escape in case you'd like to use a special character as part of the symbol.

```
> :foo-bar     
NameError: undefined local variable or method `bar' for main:Object
from (irb):10
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

> :'foo-bar'     
=> :"foo-bar"
```

So, `:foo-bar` <strike>is an invalid symbol</strike> and `:"foo-bar"` is a valid symbol.

Edit: This last part is incorrect, see peak's answer below for the correct answer.

Comment: `:foo-bar` is parsed as `:foo - bar`, so it is neither a valid nor an invalid symbol -- it is an expression involving the symbol :foo and something else named `bar`.

Comment: So in the output the return value of `:"asdfas"` is `:asdfas`. But why isn't the output `:"asdfas"`? Why are the quotation marks around `asdfas` stripped down in the output?

Comment: Because they are redundant there. It is all about human representation, that should be _understandable_ by parser. As shown above, `:foo-bar` is parsed as `:foo - bar` for obvious reason; here we need quotes to instruct parser that everything is a name of this `Symbol`. Imagine a “All for $1“ store. There are no prices on items, _unless there is some stuff, that costs $2_. The latter would be labeled.